# How to create a custom function to my struct in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, combine

So, a lot of components of SwiftUI has functions that has a code block as parameter and later is executed, for example:

```
TextField("0",text: $text)
    .onChange(of: text) { newValue in
       // some code
    }
```

or

```
VStack{}
   .onAppear {
      // some code
   }
```

I want to create a function like `onChange` where the view that contains the component can implement a block that will be executed later at some point.

I was able to replicate this behavior like this but I want to know if there is a better way to do it.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Item: View {

    @State var text: String = ""
    var vm: VM = VM()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {

            TextField("0",text: $text)
                .frame(width: 10, alignment: .center)
                .onChange(of: text) { newValue in
                    someValidation()
                }
                .onAppear()
            Rectangle()
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .frame(height: 2)
        }
    }

    func someValidation() {
        vm.block?()
    }

    func setBlock(perform: @escaping  (() -> Void)) -> some View {

        vm.block = perform
        vm.block?()
        return self
    }

    class VM {
        var block: (() -> Void)?
    }
}

struct Item_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Item()
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Here is an example of what I'm trying to actually do.
How can I send to my parent view some data or just execute some code?

Here is the view that will return a string to the parent.
[image: view that will return the textfield value at some point]

and here is the view that will handle the string return from my other view.
[image: my parent view that will store all strings returned by my other view]

Comment: I think you should rethink your approach, it would be easier to help if we knew what you actual problem was. This is rather unorthodox and likely will be a source of threading issues.

Comment: Shouldn't you just use Binding for this?

Comment: I added some images and tried to explain better what I trying to do. thanks for the help in advance

Comment: @JoakimDanielson , I think binding would solve this problem, but there is a way to implement this kind of function ? Like the .onChange function

Comment: Go through the Apple SwiftUI tutorials this is a simple `State`-`Binding`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you just need to use some bindings when passing the data. Generating an `Item` view and then telling the parent about value changes is not ideal, where is your source of truth there? Instead, you can give the `Item` view a binding to the value in your one true data source.

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct Item: View {
    @Binding var string: String
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("", text: $string)
            Rectangle().foregroundColor(.red).frame(height: 2)
        }
    }
}

struct MainView : View {
    @State var data: [String]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                ForEach(Array(data.enumerated()), id: \.0) { _, string in
                    Text(string)
                }
            }
            HStack {
                ForEach(Array($data.enumerated()), id: \.0) { _, string in
                    Item(string: string)
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 500, height: 500)
    }
}

let startingValues: [String] = [
    "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",
]

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(MainView(data: startingValues))
```

This example here extends past a simple type like String and can be used with Struct/Class too.

When you change one of the values, the array is updated and you can see this via the top HStack. Anything using the `data` array will be updated by SwiftUI bindings. This paradigm should be your go-to when using SwiftUI.

**EDIT**
You can always add an onChange modifier to `Item` itself...

```
Item(string: string)
    .onChange(of: string.wrappedValue, initial: false) {
        print("new value! \(string)")
    }
```